# mysql between query

Tags: mysql, date

I have this scheme:

```
--------------------------
| ID | data  | timestamp |
--------------------------
```

how i can make a query to show only today values?
I now i need to use the BETWEEN statement, any idea?

Comment: What format is the timestamp? is it a MySQL DATETIME or a Unix timestamp?

Comment: solved, I've been working with timestamp like varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     mytable
WHERE    DATE(timestamp) = CURDATE()
```

Or so I think.

Comment: I've inserted some bulk data into my db, but that query doesn't work.

Comment: @greenbandit: What's the datatype of "timestamp"?

Comment: varchar, since your last respond... seems like i need to change it.

Comment: @greenbandit: I would agree, especially for indexing purposes. But you can cast/convert it to a datetime for comparison, though pretty slow.

Comment: @greenbandit: glad to hear. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID, date, timestamp
from yourtable
where DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: no rows? or rows filled with blanks? Obviously, check if you've got any records that have today's date for the timestamp.

Comment: thanks, solved, bad field type, set up to timestamp and works like a charm.